# Python/MySQLdb/cursor.executemany()

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am performing a very simple query to a given MySQL database. Let's say:

```
>>> cur = mydb.cursor()
>>> results = cur.executemany("select field from table where field = %s", ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'))
>>> print results
4
```

So far so good...

```
>>> rows = cur.fetchall()
>>> print rows
field for value3
```

So the problem is that it prints answer only for `value3` and not for `value2` and `value1`

How can I fetch the entire result for the operation I am doing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
print rows
```

Try this:

```
for r in rows:
    print r
```